# Customizing Navigation Controller for all ViewControllers

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

My AppDelegate.h

```
//
//  AppDelegate.h
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    UIWindow *window;
    UITabBarController *tabBarController;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITabBarController *tabBarController;

@end
```

My AppDelegate.m

```
//
//  AppDelegate.m
//
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import "AppNavigationController.h"

#import "ExamViewController.h"
#import "SignsViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize tabBarController = _tabBarController;

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_tabBarController release];
    [_window release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    // Initializating our Tab Bar Controller
    tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    // Exam Controller Setup
    ExamViewController *examViewController = [[ExamViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    AppNavigationController *examNavigationController = [[AppNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:examViewController];

    examViewController.title = @"Экзамен";
    examViewController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_exam.png"];
    // -------------------------------------

    // Signs Controller Setup
    SignsViewController *signsViewController = [[SignsViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    AppNavigationController *signsNavigationController = [[AppNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:signsViewController];

    signsViewController.title = @"Знаки";
    signsViewController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_signs.png"];

    // -------------------------------------

    [tabBarController  setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:examNavigationController, signsNavigationController, nil]];

    [self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    [examNavigationController release];
    [examViewController release];

    [signsNavigationController release];
    [signsViewController release];

    return YES;
}
```

Also I have empty UINavigationController.

The thing I want to implement is customized navigation bar for all viewcontrollers which use it
For example: Now I have only two viewcontrollers and now I put `self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;` in viewDidLoad method in ExamViewController.m and SignsViewController.m
But probably I'd like to add two or more tabs and want to customize navigation bar in one place.
So the question is: How to customize navigation bar in one place to look the same in every viewcontroller without customizing it in each viewcontroller in viewDidLoad method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:.

1. Create anew view controller, let's say ViewControllerTemplate.h
2. set the design to the ViewControllerTemplate navigation controller in the .m file
3. Then each time you want to crate a view controller just set the ViewControllerTemplate.h as its super class, and it will inherit the design.

   ```
   ViewControllerTemplate *newController = [[ViewControllerTemplate alloc]init];
   ```

Comment: I have folder Templates and my AppNavigationController lays there, the question how to customize the view in it.

Comment: thank you, I've put self.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque; in AppNavigationController viewDidLoad method. I've tried to put self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque; before but was no results.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using iOS 5 only a new way would be `UIAppearence`. See here: [Custom Appearance for UIKit Controls](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iOS5.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30915195-SW15)

And here is another great Tutorial how to customize UI in iOS 5 by Steve Baranski:
[User Interface Customization in iOS 5](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5)

Comment: `UIAppearance` is iOS 5 only. If you need a solution for other iOS versions shannogas  answer is one way you could do it.